# Why are the rail strikes in the UK spaced out?

Tags: uk, trains

In June 2022, there have been 3 days of striking scheduled for railway staff across the UK. These are intended to be [Tuesday, Thursday and Saturday](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-61634959).

I would have expected greater disruption to the work-week and general travel if the strikes were immediately one after the other. Is there some limitation on striking multiple days in a row?

Comment: If they go in "with both guns blazing" and it fails, where do they go next? Perhaps consecutive days is the next elevation of the tactic, and they also need to keep public opinion on their side.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really about travel. Questions about how train operations will be affected during the strike would certainly be on topic here, but the union's reasoning behind their choice of which days to strike is way out of scope.

Comment: Note that in many cases, a strike on day D will also cause disruption on days D-1 and D+1 (because trains and personnel may not be where they need to be for regular operations). The impact is lower than on day D, but if you have another strike on D+2, it will be quite significant on D+1. The end result is that with just 2 days not paid, they get disruption for 3 days…

Comment: @jcaron the impact seems pretty limited for the main commuting hours on the in-between days.  Early morning and possibly late night services will be worse affected.  So they can cause hassle for the bosses on the non-strike days while allowing most commuters to get in to work - and many of us can WFH intermittently more easily than for consecutive days

Comment: @ChrisH: I do not agree. Part of the travel question is about to understand the local culture (as it affect how we travel, how we should behave). If the answer is "UK tradition", I would much more inclined to start travelling in unresting periods. And because we cannot predict the future, I think a "why?" question is what we need to get some predictions

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi If the question was "I'm planning a trip to the UK and saw there are strikes being planned. Is there anything I can do to minimise the chance of my trip being affected by further strikes?" I wouldn't vote to close. But if that was what you wanted to know, you'd ask that. This question doesn't. It asks why they chose those days and if there are limitations on striking on consecutive days. No part of that is even nearly a travel question.

Comment: @ChrisH Rather than just voting to close, perhaps you could provide some recommendations for where such a question might be better suited?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was VTCed when there's literally a similarly irrelevant question in the HNQs: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174476/why-cant-i-take-photos-inside-of-stores-in-portugal

Comment: The simple answer to the question is that they only lose three days pay but have disrupted travel for the whole week because operations have to stop earlier on non-strike days and start later. So they get maximum impact for less personal cost.

Comment: @AhmedTawfik, Each question is seen as a separate item. There is no rule that someone compares all questions and if an other has not (yet) been closed the new one can also not be closed or something like that. Other questions on the network are never a good reason to keep a question open. The question you link to is a completly different question which may stay open or not, but it is in no way relevant to your question. (And I would not know which Stack Exchange site would accept your question.)